# Find cheapest path using A* ALGORITHM

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, shortest-path, a-star

[image]

The program should start at A and check for the cheapest path to one of the goal states G1, G2, and G3.

I am getting following output, which is wrong but close, I think.

```
Cheapest path: [A, C, D, G2]
Goal state: G2
Number of cycles: 3
```

Can someone help with my code, it is not giving the right path.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class AStarSearch {
  
// define a private class Node which stores g from start node
  //stores h from current node to goal node
  
    private static final int INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    private static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        String state;
        int g;
        int h;

        Node parent;

        public Node(String state, int g, int h, Node parent) {
            this.state = state;
            this.g = g;
            this.h = h;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public int getTotalCost() {
            return g + h;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node other) {
            return Integer.compare(this.getTotalCost(), other.getTotalCost());
        }
    }
    
//takes an array of node labels, an array of heuristic values 
    //takes startstate as input
    
    private static List<String> aStarSearch(int[][] matrix, String[] labels, int[] heuristic, String startState) {
        Map<String, Integer> heuristicMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            heuristicMap.put(labels[i], heuristic[i]);
        }

        Map<String, Integer> gScores = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> fScores = new HashMap<>();
        
        //starts with start node and adds to open set
        //sets the g score and total f score of start node

        PriorityQueue<Node> openSet = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<String> closedSet = new HashSet<>();

        Node startNode = new Node(startState, 0, heuristicMap.get(startState), null);
        openSet.add(startNode);
        gScores.put(startState, 0);
        fScores.put(startState, startNode.getTotalCost());

        while (!openSet.isEmpty()) {
            Node current = openSet.poll();
            String currentState = current.state;

            if (heuristicMap.get(currentState) == 0) {
                // Reached a goal state, return the path
                List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
                Node node = current;
                while (node != null) {
                    path.add(0, node.state);
                    node = node.parent;
                }
                return path;
            }

            closedSet.add(currentState);

            for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                String nextState = labels[i];
                int cost = matrix[i][Arrays.asList(labels).indexOf(currentState)];
                if (cost > 0) {
                    int tentativeGScore = gScores.get(currentState) + cost;
                    int tentativeFScore = tentativeGScore + heuristicMap.get(nextState);

                    if (closedSet.contains(nextState) && tentativeFScore >= fScores.getOrDefault(nextState, INFINITY)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!closedSet.contains(nextState) || tentativeFScore < fScores.getOrDefault(nextState, INFINITY)) {
                        Node nextNode = new Node(nextState, tentativeGScore, heuristicMap.get(nextState), current);
                        openSet.remove(nextNode); // Remove nextNode if it's already in the openSet
                        openSet.add(nextNode);
                        gScores.put(nextState, tentativeGScore);
                        fScores.put(nextState, tentativeFScore);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // No path found
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] labels = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "J", "G1", "G2", "G3"};

        int[][] matrix = {
                {0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0}
        };

        int[] heuristic = {5, 7, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0};

        String startState = "A";

        List<String> cheapestPath = aStarSearch(matrix, labels, heuristic, startState);

        if (cheapestPath != null) {
            System.out.println("Cheapest path: " + cheapestPath);
            System.out.println("Goal state: " + cheapestPath.get(cheapestPath.size() - 1));
            System.out.println("Number of cycles: " + (cheapestPath.size() - 1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No path found.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the code above and got the output mentioned above.

Comment: Why is the image not directly visible here? What do the numbers in the image mean? If you need the path to G2, where do you start? You mentioned the result you get but not the desired result. Too many unknowns for a meaningful answer.

Comment: The image should open if you click on the link. IDK why it not displayed. 
The path to be calculated should be the cheapest. Start at A. 

I dont know the desired result, my output is definitely not correct but close.

Comment: The image is not displayed because you did not upload it here. Instead you pasted a link to another site.

Comment: I did upload the image with the option to add the image.

Comment: The numbers in image are the path cost. Figure given Search Space Example. A is the start state. G1, G2, and G3 are three goal states. The numbers in the black squares are the heuristic values which indicate the estimate cost between the state and the goal state. The numbers on the arcs indicate the path-cost between two states.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little harder to answer since you haven't provided an example input but your implementation of A* algorithm appears to be fine. However, it seems you've got a confusion about how adjacency matrices represent the graph. In adjacency matrices, the value matrix[i][j] represents the cost from node i to node j. In your current matrix, you are trying to access matrix[i][Arrays.asList(labels).indexOf(currentState)] which is effectively same as matrix[i][current.index] which is not the correct way to access the cost. Each row represents the start node and each column represents the end node. The elements of the matrix represent the cost from start node to end node.

Also If your heuristic function overestimates, A* might not find the shortest path. Make sure your heuristic values don't violate this condition.

Below i've attempted to fix what I think is your issue:

```
import java.util.*;

public class AStarSearch {
  
    private static final int INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    private static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        String state;
        int g;
        int h;

        Node parent;

        public Node(String state, int g, int h, Node parent) {
            this.state = state;
            this.g = g;
            this.h = h;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public int getTotalCost() {
            return g + h;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node other) {
            return Integer.compare(this.getTotalCost(), other.getTotalCost());
        }
    }

    private static List<String> aStarSearch(int[][] matrix, String[] labels, int[] heuristic, String startState) {
        Map<String, Integer> heuristicMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            heuristicMap.put(labels[i], heuristic[i]);
        }

        Map<String, Integer> gScores = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> fScores = new HashMap<>();

        PriorityQueue<Node> openSet = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<String> closedSet = new HashSet<>();

        Node startNode = new Node(startState, 0, heuristicMap.get(startState), null);
        openSet.add(startNode);
        gScores.put(startState, 0);
        fScores.put(startState, startNode.getTotalCost());

        while (!openSet.isEmpty()) {
            Node current = openSet.poll();
            String currentState = current.state;

            if (heuristicMap.get(currentState) == 0) {
                // Reached a goal state, return the path
                List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
                Node node = current;
                while (node != null) {
                    path.add(0, node.state);
                    node = node.parent;
                }
                return path;
            }

            closedSet.add(currentState);

            for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                String nextState = labels[i];
                int cost = matrix[Arrays.asList(labels).indexOf(currentState)][i];
                if (cost > 0) {
                    int tentativeGScore = gScores.get(currentState) + cost;
                    int tentativeFScore = tentativeGScore + heuristicMap.get(nextState);

                    if (closedSet.contains(nextState) && tentativeFScore >= fScores.getOrDefault(nextState, INFINITY)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!closedSet.contains(nextState) || tentativeFScore < fScores.getOrDefault(nextState, INFINITY)) {
                        Node nextNode = new Node(nextState, tentativeGScore, heuristicMap.get(nextState), current);
                        openSet.removeIf(node -> node.state.equals(nextState));
                        openSet.add(nextNode);
                        gScores.put(nextState, tentativeGScore);
                        fScores.put(nextState, tentativeFScore);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // No path found
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] labels = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "J", "G1", "G2", "G3"};

        int[][] matrix = {
                // Your adjacency matrix should go here
        };

        int[] heuristic = {
                // Your heuristic array should go here
        };

        String startState = "A";

        List<String> cheapestPath = aStarSearch(matrix, labels, heuristic, startState);

        if (cheapestPath != null) {
            System.out.println("Cheapest path: " + cheapestPath);
            System.out.println("Goal state: " + cheapestPath.get(cheapestPath.size() - 1));
            System.out.println("Number of cycles: " + (cheapestPath.size() - 1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No path found.");
        }
    }
}
```

The cost is now retrieved as matrix[Arrays.asList(labels).indexOf(currentState)][i], which represents the cost from the current node to the next node i

Comment: I mean an example input of of the matrix and heurstic array with the expected output. But I can see that overestimating may not be the case, so thanks!